# class creation with dojo 1.8 declare

Tags: javascript, class, dojo

I'm using dojo 1.8 as javascript library.
I'm trying to create a small Vector class for a project of mine.

I've created a function clone to clone the vector object. Here is my class "td/Vector"

```
define([
    'dojo/_base/declare',
    'td/Vector'
], function(declare, Vector) {
return declare(null, {

    x: null,
    y: null,

    constructor: function(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    },

    clone: function() {
        return new Vector(this.x, this.y);
    },

    length: function() {
        return Math.sqrt((this.x * this.x) + (this.y * this.y));
    },

    normalize: function() {
        var length = this.length();
        this.x = this.x / length;
        this.y = this.y / length;
    },

    distance: function(target) {
        return new Vector(target.x - this.x, target.y - this.y);
    }
});
});
```

Now my problem:

The variable "Vector" is an empty object.

So how can I do something like this. Does something like "self" in PHP exist in JavaScript? What is the correct way to create a new instance of self in the class itself?

Comment: i also tried "new self()" but self references the window object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Vector` variable is the return value of `td/Vector` module, i.e. `td/Vector.js` file, not the class you `declare` above, which should be the reason it is an empty object.

To reference the class itself:

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {

    var Vector = declare(null, {    

        constructor: function(x, y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        },

        clone: function() {
            return new Vector(this.x, this.y);
        }
    });

    return Vector;

});
```

See it in action at jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/QYBdv/